# Yii PHP Add Pagination to my site

Tags: php, yii

I would like to add pagination to my website, but I am very new to Yii and would like some advise.

This is the page that I am looking to add pagination: https://gocar2.com/newsproducts/center

As you can see I have numerous cells for each auto news, and now I am allowing only 18 news to show on the page. I would like to add pagination here so that I can browse more news.

And this is what I tried:

newscontroller.php

```
<?php

use yii\data\Pagination;

class NewsproductsController extends Controller
{
public function actionCentermore()
{   

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition("approvedStatus = '1'");
    $criteria->order = 'createdDate DESC';
    $product = Newsproducts::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $Pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 15,
        'totalCount' => $product->count(),
    ]);

    $products = $product->offset($Pagination->offset)
    ->limit($Pagination->limit)
    ->all();

    $this->renderPartial('centermore',compact('products', 'Pagination'));

}
}
```

newsview.php will render all the top menu and banners and it will render centermore.php

```
$this->renderPartial('centermore', compact('products', 'Pagination'));
```

centermore.php (view of the news cells), I then added the LinkPager widget at the bottom.

```
LinkPager::widget(['Pagination' => $Pagination])
```

And of course, there is an error, Class LinkPager cannot be found. 
Can anyone give me some advise how to solve this/implement paging?

Comment: Which version of Yii you're using?

Comment: there is no `CDbCriteria` in `Yii2` you action code is for `yii1` and you are using the widget for yii2

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 pagination is usually handled via `DataProvider`, have a look at the:
[Yii2 Guide: Data Providers](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers), especially `ActiveDataProvider`:

```
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

$query = Post::find()->where(['status' => 1]);

$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'created_at' => SORT_DESC,
            'title' => SORT_ASC, 
        ]
    ],
]);

// returns an array of Post objects
$posts = $provider->getModels();
```